# Sequence of Importing Modules statements in Angular

Tags: angular, performance

Hope everyone is safe and doing great.

I was curious to know also googled and reading articles on Angular.io to get out of confusion from ordering of import.

**Does it matter order of keeping importing modules which required in a component or in service in angular.**

Such as **adding third party Lib like *"moment"* does it matter of keeping a sequence if I import this module to top of components or add in last before @component or @injectable decorator**.

Does it count on performance if we keep change order . I understand in built angular does prepared a tree shakable bundle of whatever modules imports in features modules or component or in service used

Please share/suggest if there's is any guide or documents convincing standard practice of same.